# Pandas Dataframe Min/Max Range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Thank you in advance for helping!    (Code below) / Data Here: [Link](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/AllDeepSoilData.zip?raw=true)

I am trying to add two more columns to my dataframe that represent the range of data for the Topsoil column, just like mean['maxx20']=maxx['20 cm'] and mean['minn20']=minn['20 cm'] do for the 20 cm column.

I tried doing that by adding:

```
mean['topsoilMax']=maxx['Topsoil']
mean['topsoilMin']=minn['Topsoil']
```

Instead of adding the additional columns as I had hoped, this caused **KeyError: 'Topsoil'** even though Topsoil was already a column in the data frame, just like 20 cm was for when I added the ranges for that.

Why am I getting this error and what would be the proper way to add these columns?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

#Importing data, creating a copy, and assigning it to a variable
raw_data = pd.read_csv('all-deep-soil-temperatures.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df_all_stations = raw_data.copy()

#Setting the program to iterate based off of the station of the users choice
selected_soil_station = 'Minot'
df_selected_station = df_all_stations[df_all_stations['Station'] == selected_soil_station]
df_selected_station.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace=True);

# Indexes the data by day and creates a column that keeps track of the day
df_selected_station_D=df_selected_station.resample(rule='D').mean()
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.dayofyear


#Assigning variable so that mean represents df_selected_station_D but indexed by day
mean=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').mean()
mean['Day']=mean.index

#This inserts a new column named 'Topsoil' at the end that represents the average between 5 cm, 10 cm, and 20 cm
mean['Topsoil']=mean[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm']].mean(axis=1)


#Creating the range in which the line graph will fill in 
maxx=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').max()
minn=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').min()

mean['maxx20']=maxx['20 cm']
mean['minn20']=minn['20 cm']
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably needed to add "Topsoil" columns to maxx and minn dataframes:

```
maxx['Topsoil']=maxx[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm']].max(axis=1)
minn['Topsoil']=minn[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm']].min(axis=1)
```

After that assignment works:

```
mean['topsoilMax']=maxx['Topsoil']
mean['topsoilMin']=minn['Topsoil']
```

Comment: I think this is selecting the min and the max from these three, but the Topsoil column is supposed to be the average of those three. So, I believe that the logic should be that new columns are the range of the average of those three on that date. Kind of like this (This isn't actually how you would code it haha):

maxx['Topsoil']=maxx[[Average('5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm')]].max(axis=1)

Comment: Maybe I don't get it right, but why dont use `maxx['Topsoil']=mean[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm']].max(axis=1)` in that case? mean[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm'] should already contain average values.

Comment: I figured it out, I ended up adding more columns that represent the ranges for 5 cm and 10 cm like this:

Comment: mean['maxx05']=maxx['5 cm']
mean['minn05']=minn['5 cm']
mean['maxx10']=maxx['10 cm']
mean['minn10']=minn['10 cm']

Comment: Then I averaged those three and I got the result I was looking for.  I wouldn't have been able to do so without your direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly then my way solution is,

```
topsoil = [-2.971686,-2.599278,-2.264897,-2.083117,-1.946969]

max_number = max(topsoil)
min_number = min(topsoil)
print(max_number)  #Here you get the max number of the topsoil list
print(min_number) #Here you get the min number of the topsoil list
print(max_number - min_number) #Here you get the max -min number of the topsoil list
```

Here is the solution

[image: screenshot]